# Moment js utc() time in london - BST

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm using momentjs lib to updated text on some ajax action. What I need to do is to set a current date & time in london. I'm using moment.utc() function but because of the summer time I'm one hour out.

For example running this on 14:26

```
console.log( moment.utc().format('HH:mm:ss') );
```

I'm getting 13:26:53.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `utc()` if you want a local time? Surely it's behaving exactly as expected...

Comment: I don't want local time but London time

Comment: Regardless of where the user is? That's going to give quite an odd experience, I'd say - but Takuya's answer should have you covered. Could you explain more about why you want this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you use [momentJS timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)?

moment().tz('Europe/London');

EDIT: In case you try to use this without seeing the link, it's a separate library you have to include.

Comment: How to get the PST time?
I tried with this 

```var dec = moment();
const pst = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a z');

console.log(pst)
```

It gives PDT time always. Any suggestions please?

Comment: @shanmugharaj I believe you have to give it a time that is within PST to start with. For example:

moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/Los_Angeles').format('zz'); // PST
moment.tz([2012, 5], 'America/Los_Angeles').format('zz'); // PDT

See: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score 4):

If you want the local time instead of the UTC time, just use `moment()` instead of `moment.utc()`. You're specifically *asking* for UTC, so you shouldn't be surprised when you *get* UTC :)

From the documentation:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.
>
> This brings us to an interesting feature of Moment.js. UTC mode.
>
> While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.

This is assuming you always want the user's local time. If you want a specific time zone (London) which may *not* be the user's time zone and isn't UTC, then you should use the library indicated by Takuya's answer. I would think carefully before doing so though - while it *may* be a sensible approach, you should at least validate that first. It's often reasonable to display a time for user U<sub>1</sub> in the time zone of user U<sub>2</sub> - but here you're using a *fixed* time zone. That's only appropriate if you know that U<sub>2</sub> will always be in London. It would be *really* confusing if actually U<sub>2</sub> is in some other zone - either the same as or different to U<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: Problem with moment() is that it uses local time on the user's computer, e.g. won't work properly if the user is outside of London or has set the time and timezone wrong on the device.

Comment: @Takuya: Yes, I'd assumed that the OP wanted the local time for the user - if they always want London time regardless of the user's time zone, then using Europe/London makes sense... although it's a very odd design decision to start with.

Comment: yes, perhaps odd, but we don't know the use case. Bookmarked your blog btw.

Comment: I'll argue that there are plenty of good use cases for using a time zone other than the user's own local time zone.  For example, consider a call center UI, where the operator sees the caller's local time on the screen and in the call logs.  Also consider just a simple bit of script that shows whether a business location is currently open or closed on their web site.  They'll want to compare business hours against the local time zone of that business, even if the user is on the other side of the world.  I'm sure there are lots of other use cases as well.

Comment: @MattJohnson: True - but those are all talking about someone else's time zone rather than another *fixed* time zone. I guess if you assume all your callers are from the UK, that makes sense. I'd still like it if the OP could give more context - it *may* be appropriate, but it may not be... Editing my answer to be a little less forthright :)